# Swift 画像をデータベースへ

Tags: swift2

Swiftで画像をデータベースへアップすることは可能ですか？

My SQLを想定していますがその場合型はなにになりますか？画像 BLOBですか？

また OracleとRealmとどっちがいいですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q. 画像データを複数個（任意個）サーバに保存しておくに最適なソリューションは？
と読み替えさせてもらいます（ [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) 関係なし)

短い答え：最適解は要件によって異なります

長い答え：
データベースを使う（プログラマにとっての）メリットは

- 検索が高速なこと
- 差分管理ができること
- バックアップ等のツールが充実していること

一方、画像データ自体を保存する目的にデータベースを使ってもデータベースソフトが得意な形での検索する機会がまず絶対にないので、これだけでもうデータベースを使う意味が半減どころか皆無です。画像ファイルを画像ファイルとしてアクセスできる構造のほうが余計なオーバーヘッドがかからなくて処理が高速になり、末端顧客としてはそっちのほうがうれしいかもしれません。

# オイラの知り合いのカメラ好きは 256GB CF を数枚用意して、現地での撮影の際はひたすら撮影、空き時間にノートパソコンに複写して CF は再フォーマット、練習走行から予選決勝までの間に撮影データ量はテラバイトに達して、帰宅してから整理、ってしてます。そういうユーザが100人いれば、一時的であってもサーバ側に要求される記憶装置容量はエクサの桁が必要。

どういうユーザが何人いてどんな使い方するか、の案件分析がないまま仕様選定の話をしているので、まとまるものもまとまらないです。